# Getting User from OleDb Connection String

Tags: c#

Trying to get the User Id from my Oledb Connection string.

Am using the following approach.

```
string user = 
conn.ConnectionString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .First(s = s.StartsWith("User")));

connection string: 
Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=COSQAC;User Id=BERNARD;Password=;Default Collection=MYLIB;
```

a) What am I missing to get this to work?

b) the connection string builder does not specify a .User (like for SQL). Is that correct (and could I use the keys

Comment: First, what is the problem, apart from the fact you are retrieving the entire key-value pair? Secon, the builder does actually have a User Id property, check the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and the first example in the Remarks section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you asking. Your code, after fixing the typos, should return the entire key-value pair for `User Id`:

```
var conStr="Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=COSQAC;User Id=BERNARD;Password=;Default Collection=MYLIB;";
var user=conStr.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .First(s => s.StartsWith("User"));
```

This will return `User Id=BERNARD`. You can split this on `=` to get the user Id.

Or you can use a regular expression to extract the User Id directly:

```
var match=Regex.Match(conStr,"User Id=(?<name>.*?);");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value);
```

This returns `BERNARD`. The pattern catches only the characters between `User Id=` and the next `;` in a group named `name`.

The [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) *does* support `User Id` although you need to use the indexer to set or get it. OLEDB providers have different parameter names so there is no guarantee that the parameter even exists for a specific provider:

```
var builder = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(conStr);
var user=builder["User Id"];
```

This will return `BERNARD`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class with MS SQL.

It could look like this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
var userId = builder.UserID;
```

Don't forget to add namespases:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

But in your case you can use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder  builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
var userId = builder["User Id"];
```

namespace `System.Data.OleDb`

Comment: The question is about an OLEDB connection to an AS/400 mainframe. You can't use SqlConnectionBuilder for this

Comment: Just replace it with OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.  The concept is there.  User should have tagged question as AS/400 or iSeries IMO.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, my bad. Corrected

Comment: Again, appreciate your help chaps - well spotted @PanagiotisKanavos re AS400

Answer (score 0):

Just one more option but with Regex

```
var connection = "Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=COSQAC;User Id=BERNARD;Password=;Default Collection=MYLIB;";
var pattern = "User Id=([a-zA-Z-_]*);";
//var pattern = "User Id=([^;]*)"; // or this one - it will get any string, untill ; will be met
var result = Regex.Match(connection,pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This could fail if the user name contains characters like '-' or '_'